# Hide URL from Inno Setup download page

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I would like to hide the URL from which the files are being downloaded.

I can't find this information.

Any hints of doing this?

[image: Message label to be hidden]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the `Msg2Label` label from the page's client area:

```pascal
DownloadPage.Msg2Label.Top := ScaleY(-100);
```

*(thanks to @MDenis for correction)*

---

*Note that this won't prevent people from finding the URL from where you are downloading the files.*

Comment: Great !

Exactly what i wanted !

Thanks.

K